# @material-ui/core - How to set Textarea Value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

Im new to this plugin and could not find any documentation regarding my question.

I want to simply apply a value to the `textarea`. I started by giving it an `id`, but there are multiple html components that make up this textarea, ad more that ons instance of the `id` I added.

The value I enter gets saved, but when I reopen the modal, its suppose to load the text that was saved for that specific area.

```
<TextField
    className="bd_textarea"
    id={ `tt_description_text outlined-multiline-static`}
    label="Pain description"
    multiline
    rows={5}
    onBlur={ (f)=>(this.textOnBlur({id:answeringPainSpot.spotId, value:f.target.value, doc_name:answeringPainSpot.doc_name})) }
/>
```

Here are my attempts on both `class` and `id` and none worked.

```
        $(".bd_textarea").val(spot_text);
        $(".bd_textarea").next().find('textarea').eq(0).val(spot_text);
        $('.bd_textarea').find('textarea').val(spot_text);

        $("#tt_description_text").val(spot_text);
        $("#tt_description_text").next().find('textarea').eq(0).val(spot_text);
        $('#tt_description_text').find('textarea').val(spot_text);
```

This is the code when renderd.

```
<p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body1" id="modal-modal-description" sx="[object Object]">
   <div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root bd_textarea"> 
       <label class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated" data-shrink="false" for="tt_description_text outlined-multiline-static" id="tt_description_text outlined-multiline-static-label">Pain description</label>
       <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInput-underline MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInput-formControl MuiInputBase-multiline MuiInput-multiline">
           <textarea aria-invalid="false" id="tt_description_text outlined-multiline-static" rows="5" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input MuiInputBase-inputMultiline MuiInput-inputMultiline"></textarea>
       </div>
   </div>
</p>
```

Comment: try $("#tt_description_text").html(spot_text);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try setting the value like this:

```
<textarea
    className="form-control"
    rows="4"
    placeholder="Add a comment"
    value={this.state.newComment}
    onChange={(e) => {
       this.setState({
          newComment: e.target.value,
       );
    }}>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Yep, that worked fine for me. Still need a bit of work so it can differentiate between textareas, but my question has been answered.